# JS: Generate objects, which are connected dynamically via parent field

Tags: javascript

I need to generate some objects, which represents DB documents and I need to 'connect' them via parent reference. The objects are pretty simple.

The main problem for me is to define the **input**

The objects should be connected in a variable way: I would like to call a function with some parameters to get the result data.To make it a bit easier to understand here an example.

The structure of the needed result data could look like this:

```
- main
  - group
  - group
    - item
    - item
  - item
- main
```

So for this the result **output** should be:

```
[
  { _id: 'main1ID' },
  { _id: 'group1ID', parent: 'main1ID', type: 'group' },
  { _id: 'group2ID', parent: 'main1ID', type: 'group' },
  { _id: 'item1ID', parent: 'group1ID', type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'item2ID', parent: 'group1ID', type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'item3ID', parent: 'main1ID', type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'main2ID' },
]
```

As you can see a main element can have group or items as children or even have no child.
Groups can also have no child at all or items as children.

So I tried to start with a basic function, but I even don't know how to define the parameters to get this function working dynamically :-(

`generateContent(2, 2, 3)` could create two main object, two groups and three items, **but there is no information, how they should be connected to each other**. And this is the main problem for me...

```
function generateContent (main = 0, group = 0, item = 0) {
  const mainDocs = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= main; i++) {
    mainDocs.push({
      _id: Random.id()
    })
  }
  // do similiar thing for group and item
  // return everything
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with defining the input. What input do you actually need to process? Is it text, is it user provided input? Are they strings? How is the relation defined in the input? If you don't know that, then which problem are you trying to solve? (What use has a program when you don't have concrete input?)

Comment: `2, 2, 3` doesn't explain who is parent and who is child

Comment: @trincot Exactly. I don't know how to define the input. The data I showed in the post should be the result output. So there should not be any data input, but only the amount of elements and how they are connected. And this is my problem.

Comment: @Bharadwaj You are totally right. I know that. And as I tried to explain in the post, this is my problem. How do I define the input parameters to get the result data as shown in the post?

Comment: I think you do not have any better choice, than describe needed structure before generation =( But if you need just brainfuckway to just generate it, you could pass something like:

```
    0112230
    // where 0 - main; 1 - group; 2 - item in group; 3 - item in main
```
It will work, but it will be totally unreadable ;D

Comment: @user3142695 based on the input there are many possibilities like `main1` may not contain values at all! so it is difficult to identify which child belongs to which parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to encode in your input the relations. It is not enough to indicate the number of each type of node. There are several encodings you could think of. A very concise one would be a string pattern like the following:

```
m(gg(ii)i)m
```

Here each letter represents the type of node to produce, and the parentheses make clear how they should relate to each other.

Here is a function that would parse such a string into the final array:

```js
function generateContent (pattern) {
    const mainDocs = [],
        parents = [],
        count = { m:0, g:0, i:0 };
    let obj, parent;
    for (let ch of pattern) {
        if (ch === '(') {
            parents.push(parent);
            parent = obj._id;
        } else if (ch === ')') {
            parent = parents.pop();
        } else {
            let type = { m: 'main', g: 'group', i: 'item' }[ch];
            obj = {
                _id: type + (++count[ch]) + 'ID'
            };
            if (parent) obj.parent = parent;
            if (ch !== 'm') obj.type = type;
            mainDocs.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return mainDocs;
}

// Example:
const result = generateContent('m(gg(ii)i)m');
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```